# assert_frame_equal export dataframes and diff on failed assertion

Tags: python, pandas, assertion

I am testing the equality of multiple dataframes.

```
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(
            df_py, df_mat, check_dtype=False, check_less_precise=True)
```

I would like to export the dataframes upon failed assertion.
How do I capture it?

It would be great if I could also save the results of the assertion check in an object of the same shape of the two dataframes. I believe that would look like a dataframe with boolean True/False for each compared element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to export the dataframes upon failed assertion. How do I capture it?

`try-except` on `AssertionError`, then do whatever you want with the dataframes

> It would be great if I could also save the results of the assertion check in an object of the same shape of the two dataframes. I believe that would look like a dataframe with boolean True/False for each compared element.

There is not an elegant way to achieve that. This can't be done using `assert_frame_equal`. You could do `df1 == df2` but this is not as nearly as sophisticated as the comparison and reporting that `assert_frame_equal` offers. For example, it works if and only if both the dataframes have the same shape **and** the same column names.

If you are using a testing framework you might need to re-raise the exception using `raise` for the test to be marked as failing.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3], 'b': [3, 5]})
try:
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_dtype=False, check_less_precise=True)
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(df1 == df2)
    raise
```

The above will output

```
DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="a") are different

DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="a") values are different (50.0 %)
[index]: [0, 1]
[left]:  [1, 2]
[right]: [1, 3]
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
```

A last resort would be to manually iterate and compare each value in both dataframes but then you need to decide how the output would look like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, however catching the exception makes the test pass (I am using pytest). Any fix to have it still marked as failed?

Comment: @Gio yeah, just add `raise` in the `except` block

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as handling the exception?

```
import traceback
try:
    assert_frame_equal(df1,df2)
except AssertionError:
    df1.to_csv('df1.csv', index=False)
    df2.to_csv('df2.csv', index=False)
    with open('traceback.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, however catching the exception makes the test pass (I am using pytest). Any fix to have it still marked as failed?